# Killing a screen without a specific session #

Tags: linux, centos, kill, gnu-screen

To create a screen, I am currently doing:

```
screen -dmS screenname ./file
```

That works perfectly, however killing it remotely with:

```
screen -X -S screenname exit
```

Will reply with:

```
No screen session found
```

This is due to the screen having {session#}.{screenname}

It will work if done as:

```
screen -X -S session#.screenname exit
```

What solutions are possible? I'm not entirely sure that you can get the session# when you start the screen. This is all done remotely too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also start screens with the -dmS option, and I send commands to the screen using the stuff command:

```
$ screen -dmS screenname
$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
    22941.screenname        (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-user.

$ screen -S screenname -p 0 -X stuff "exit$(printf \\r)"
$ screen -ls
No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-user.

$
```

more details on "stuff" are in the screen man page, search for 'stuff string'

Answer (score 0):

screen -ls | grep detached | cut -d. -f1 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill

This will kill all the detached screens

screen -ls | grep pts | cut -d. -f1 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill

this will kill all the screen whether attached or detached doesn't bother